# Deserializing and working with a JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'am trying to Read from a Deserilized Json Object.
Currently I am using the following code to deserialize the JSON data:

```
var jsondecode = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies.Get("wrkb").Value);
```

Content of my JSON object :

```
{{
  "shoppingbasket": [
    {
      "price": 12,
      "product": "Lachum",
      "quantity": 2,
      "total": 24
    },
    {
      "price": 2,
      "product": "Laici",
      "quantity": 3,
      "total": 12
    },
    {
      "price": 12,
      "product": "Lachum",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": 12
    }
  ]
}}
```

I want to convert this JSON string into a collection of .Net objects that I can work with.

For example, I would like to be able to product this type of output after I have deserialized the object.

```
Shoppingbasket:
1) Product = Lachum, Price = 12, Quantity = 3, Total = 36
2) Product = Laici, Price = 2, Quantity = 3, Total = 6

Total-Price of basket = 42
```

This was my solution but, pstrjds's solution elegant :

```
 DataSet dataSet = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(Request.Cookies.Get("wrkb").Value);
    DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["shoppingbasket"];

    string print = "";
    double basket_total = 0.0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        print = "Product= " + row["product"] + " Price= " + row["price"] + " Quantity= " + row["quantity"] + " Total= " + row["total"];
        basket_total += Convert.ToInt32(row["total"]);
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="col-md-12">
                <li><div class="col-md-12">@print</div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
```

Now I have to fix duplicated Items

Comment: Could you clarify your question further. What do you mean by "How should I read from this object?" You are showing that you are deserializing it, what exactly are you stuck on? JSON.Net has a generic deserialize option, make a class for your expected data and deserialize an array of those objects.

Comment: I mean how can i work with this object? Is it a array ?

Comment: I have reworded the question slightly and fixed the broken JSON (there were some quotes missing). Please feel free to edit if I have not correctly restated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a class to work with the returned objects (assuming you know what you are getting ahead of time).

```
public class ShoppingbasketItem
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string product { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}
public class Shoppingbasket
{
    public List<ShoppingbasketItem> shoppingbasket { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize the objects into your C# code and then do whatever you would need to with them from there.

```
var products = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Shoppingbasket>(Request.Cookies.Get("wrkb").Value);
```

So to compute a sum of the total you could just iterate the list from the basket.

```
double totalSum = 0.0;
foreach(var item in products.shoppingbasket)
{
    totalSum += item.quantity * item.price;
}
```

**Edit**
To achieve the grouping you are looking for, you could do something like this. It is probably not the best solution, but off the top of my head it is what I thought of.

```
var grouped = new Dictionary<string, ShoppingbasketItem>();

foreach (var item in products.shoppingbasket)
{
    ShoppingbasketItem temp = null;
    if (grouped.TryGetValue(item.product, out temp))
    {
        temp.quantity += item.quantity;
        temp.total += item.total;
    }
    else
    {
        grouped[item.product] = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be the best solution for me! But how can I sum up Items that exist twice or more?

Comment: @cgame92 - I have added an edit showing one way to achieve the grouping. In general on SO you post a new question rather than adding comments or modifying the original question to ask the new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a type for the deserialization, you'll get a jObject. Its properties are deduced on runtime.

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Now, there's an another way to get a jObject.

```
var result = jObject.Parse(json);
var sessionKey = p.GetValue("SessionKey").Value<string>();
```

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645034/jobject-parse-vs-jsonconvert-deserializeobject). There is no real difference whether to use deserialize or parse if you don't know of the type ahead (as in your case). Either way, you'll get a jObject.