# How do I deserialize dynamic JsonProperty?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have a json

```
"1593263898657":{"id":1593263898657,"timeToday":[17,0],"name"= "ABCD"},
"1593263898700":{"id":1593263898700,"timeToday":[17,0],"name"= "ABCD"}"
```

The class of the json is known to me i.e

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public List<int> timeToday { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("1593263898657")]
    public BaseClass B1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("1593263898700")]
    public BaseClass B2 { get; set; }
}

var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

but the problem is while deserializing I don't know how many  json property will be there in Root class, so I need to generate the json property dynamically, how can I do that?

Eg:
Root class may contain B3,B4... respectively so I do not want to hardcode!

Comment: I think you are looking for a Dictionary. `Dictionary<long, BaseClass>` ?

Comment: You could deserialize the object with JObject.Parse see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645034/jobject-parse-vs-jsonconvert-deserializeobject

Comment: @casenonsensitive What benefit would there be in doing so? You'd still have to know in advance, how many BX you'll have. Or restrict yourself to a fix number. Or put them in a Dictionary - where you can also have them deserialized automatically.

Comment: if that's all of your JSON, then it's **invalid**. when including samples of JSON, _please_ take care that your sample is representative and as valid as the full blob.

Comment: @Fildor Dictionary<long, BaseClass> solution worked for me Thanks !!.