# How to count the length of value array in JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON below:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "504896c031d2fcb9",
      "location": "North Europe",
      "properties": {
        "state": "UNKNOWN",
        "name": "504896c031d2fcb9",
        "siteInstanceName": "504896c031d2fcb93ec",
        "healthCheckUrl": null,
        "machineName": "lw0s",
        "containers": null
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "35aafa",
      "location": "North Europe",
      "properties": {
        "state": "UNKNOWN",
        "name": "35aafae",
        "siteInstanceName": "35aafaeff",
        "healthCheckUrl": null,
        "machineName": "lw1s",
        "containers": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "nextLink": null,
  "id": null
}
```

I have converted JSON to a dynamic as mentioned below:

```cs
string kq = reader.ReadToEnd();
dynamic jss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(kq);
```

I want to know how to count how many values in C#? The above example has 2 values.

Thank you.

Comment: why are you de-serializing to `dynamic` instead of a named class? Anyway you may just use `jss.value.Length`.

Comment: a named class take time to write :(

Comment: if it's okay for you to scratch your head in a few months because you cannot remember how your data-structure looks like only because you've been to lazy to invest a few seconds to extract a class from given data... it's your program.

Comment: Agree with @HimBromBeere - I can't think of many times when developing in C# that I've had to use dynamic. Dynamic typing has it's place, but this isn't it

Answer (score 1):

if you know the key you can do something like

```
 dynamic jss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(kq);
 jss["value"].Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast as `JArray` and `.Count`.

Perhaps, if the `value` is not an array type, casted `array` will return as `null`.

You may add handling to check whether it is not `null` and get `.Count`.

```cs
dynamic jss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(kq);
JArray array = jss["value"] as JArray;
Console.WriteLine(array != null ? array.Count : 0);
```

[Sample program (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tCdAhW)

---

### Recommendation:

Since you are deserializing JSON string to `dynamic`, with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` it will return the value of `JObject` type.

I would suggest using `JObject.Parse` rather than `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` (which is designed for converting to strongly-type object).

You may read this question: [JObject.Parse vs JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24645588/8017690) for more info.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject jss = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray array = jss["value"] as JArray;
Console.WriteLine(array != null ? array.Count : 0);
```

[Sample program (JObject.Parse)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BLJMJS)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it