# JObject Not Parsing Values I need

Tags: c#, json, parsing

```
String Contents =
{
    "links":[
    {
        ".tag":"file",
        "url":"myURL",
        "id":"CCCCC",
        "name":"CCCC",
        "path_lower":"CCCC"
    },
    {
        "url".. and so on.
    }

    JObject json = JObject.Parse(contents);
    Console.WriteLine(json.GetValue("links.url"));
```

I am trying to get all the URL values and store them into an array. The problem is that this code does not parse anything.

The main `json` is links and the rest is under it. How can I go about getting all the URL values?

Comment: Loop through links array?

Comment: @Llama My current code does not even parse just the url values I need. How will a loop help??

Comment: If you wanted to use JPath you could do `json.SelectToken("links[0].url")` but that will only get you the first object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take `json["links"]` as `JArray`.
2. Use Linq to retrieve `url` from the element in (1) and cast it to `string`.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject json = JObject.Parse(contents);
JArray array = json["links"] as JArray;

List<string> links = array.Select(x => (string)x["url"]).ToList();
```

[Sample demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lRZHdN)

Comment: You my sir are the best!!! This worked perfect.  One quick question. Why was JArray needed?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Because `links` is an array. You have to cast as `JArray` before retrieving each element in the array. And wish you enjoy the festive season.

Comment: Sounds great! Two more questions. 1. How efficient is this method? 2. How do I know if a JSON is an array?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 1. For efficiency, it depends on how is your JSON object. Whether is your JSON object is dynamic or not, the size. This article [JObject.Parse vs JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645034/jobject-parse-vs-jsonconvert-deserializeobject) may be useful for you. 2. when the object/property has the [value surrounded with `[]`](https://restfulapi.net/json-array/).

Comment: So another issue. This code sometimes does not work when it is a single JSOn and not an array. How can I check to see if its an Array or not easily? ALso how would I parse that single JSOn?

Comment: Bascially I need to see if the data contains Links or not. If it contains links its an array, if it does not contain links its a single object.  

if (json.ContainsKey("links")) would this work?

Comment: This [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XMf4Tu) may meet your requirement.

Comment: This concept is nice, but for the JSOn object that is not an array, it does not start with links or anything. It justs all the values listed. So would it be all this: JObject jLink = json as JObject; Then var link = (string)jLink["url"];