# Reflect an unknown object to get property names and values C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to get the property names and their corresponding values of an unknown object.

This is what I came up with as a test, but I am getting a "Parameter Count Mismatch" error when calling `prop.GetValue(myObj)`

```
FundingPastDueEvent _event = new FundingPastDueEvent()
{
    InvoiceCount = 123
};

var nsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_event);

var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(nsJson);

var properties = myObj.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {prop.GetValue(myObj)}");
}
```

Comment: Is one of the properties indexed?  See the method signatures for indexed properties here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0

Comment: See PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters?view=net-6.0

Comment: @adv12 no, not indexed. You can see the object in the example `FundingPastDueEvent`

Comment: So `FundingPastDueEvent` just has one member called `InvoiceCount` having a type of `int`?

Comment: OK, let's see the contents of `nsJson`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OP is checking properties of Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject (you can ignore type they have as a sample), indeed it has indexed properties.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24645588/2557128) on how `DeserializeObject` handles `object` as the target type