# C# effective way to get JSON property value from nested JSON response

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am getting a HTTP response as JSON string. I am converting the response as JObject.
Response contains "sessions" node and it contains more sessions value
each sessions contains "events" with  one or multiple "events"
each events contains "Type" and "ArbitaryData"
ArbitaryData contains "interest".

I am trying to take all the "interest" values, from all the sessions and all the events but if the event type = "search".

what's the effective way to do that other than doing for loop?

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(guestJsonResponse);
 var sessions = json.SelectToken("sessions");
 var events = sessions.SelectTokens("events");
```

Below is my JSON string response example

```
  {
  "firstName":"fn",
  "lastName":"ln",
   "gender":"male",
  "sessions":[
  {
     "currency":"USD",
     "events":[
        {
           "type":"SEARCH",
           "status":"PROCESSED",
           "arbitraryData":{
              "interest":"Health"
           }
        },
        {
           "type":"CHECK",
           "status":"PROCESSED",
           "arbitraryData":{
              "interest":"Dental"
           }
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "currency":"USD",
     "events":[
        {
           "type":"SEARCH",
           "status":"PROCESSED",
           "arbitraryData":{
              "interest":"Health"
           }
        },
        {
           "type":"CHECK",
           "status":"PROCESSED",
           "arbitraryData":{
              "interest":"Dental"
           }
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "currency":"USD",
     "events":[
        {
           "type":"SEARCH",
           "status":"PROCESSED",
           "arbitraryData":{
              "interest":"Health"
           }
        },
        {
           "type":"CHECK",
           "status":"PROCESSED",
           "arbitraryData":{
              "interest":"Dental"
           }
        }
     ]
  }
   ]
     }
```

Comment: You could create a DTO class, parse the JSON into an instance of that class and then use LINQ to filter out unwanted objects in the list

Comment: Take a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645034/jobject-parse-vs-jsonconvert-deserializeobject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code  will return all the "interest" values, from all the sessions where the event type = "SEARCH"

```
List<string> interests = ((JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["sessions"])
                              .SelectMany(i => ((JArray)i["events"]))
                              .Where(x => (string)x["type"] == "SEARCH")
                              .Select(x => (string)x["arbitraryData"]["interest"])
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: Code only answer.

Comment: @PoulBak "I am trying to take all the "interest" values, from all the sessions and all the events but if the event type = "search". This is my answer

Comment: I don't need an explanation, but OP and later searchers might.

Comment: Please mark as solution if this is your answer @user1428019

Comment: @PoulBak I added some description